# Interaction of two sound emitting particles in a medium

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, waves, interference

Consider a free particle at rest suspended in an infinite medium.

If the particle becomes the source of a sound wave in one direction, will the particle start to move in the opposite direction due to an opposing force from the produced wave?

If the particle instead produces that wave in all directions, will the particle stay at rest because of the cancellation of the forces?

If a similar particle (i.e., producing a sound wave in all directions) is placed in the vicinity of the original particle, I want to know if there will be any kind of interaction between the two particles because of interference of the two waves. Specifically, will the particles repel each other, or attract each other, or absolutely nothing will happen and they’ll continue to stay at rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our source particle is unique. Its driving the medium. It is the origin of the vibrations that have now spread out in the medium. It decides its state.

Consider the unidirectional case. Since it acts on the medium, the medium pushes back. For sound waves, this means that as the particle moves to compress its surroundings, it increases the pressure in the medium in its neighborhood. The increased pressure then pushes back. Similarly for rarefaction.

This is similar to the movement of air in a half-pipe being driven at the closed end. There is clearly pressure variation from the vibrating air at the closed end.

For the omnidirectional case, I fail to see how a single point particle can generate omnidirectional sound waves.

Lets say the particle isn't really a point particle but has some size. The net force due to the surrounding air on such a 'throbbing' particle is zero by isotropy, but the pressure isn't. So its sound would still have the characteristics of the unidirectional case, without any motion of the particle's center of mass, though I won't characterise it as "not moving". (remember that in the unidirectional case, the particle moves).

So the net motion of the source particle is determined by the reaction of the medium and the force driving it. In this, it acts as a driven oscillator. I think the sound waves will show resonance.

For another source particle in the vicinity, due to the superposition principle, the sound wave at all points in the medium would be the sum of the sounds as if the other wasn't present. Also, if the phase difference between the periodic motion of the two sources, stays constant, a stable interference pattern will emerge.

However this isn't possible, in general.

First of all, note that the interference, if it occurs, is a consequence of the interaction of the two sources, not the other way around.

Each source affects the other by producing sound that reaches the other particle. In this way, the couple to each other - we have coupled driven oscillators now.

Coupled oscillators do not in general maintain a constant phase difference unless they are vibrating in-phase, hence interference isn't possible in general.

Also since the motion of each particle is periodic, the average position of the particles don't change. So their relative position also doesn't change; they do interact but position wise, on average, they stay where they were at the start, so no effective repulsion or attraction.

Answer (score 0):

A sound wave is based on vibration and the out-sending vibrating energy touches the neighbor particles and brings them to re-vibrate. But where is the energy coming from? There is for me only one solution, that there is Spin-Force involved to transform the vibration from one place to the next. Because Spin-Force is a basic energy of momentum that transforms motion, as well as frequency and wavelength into neighborhood. That means that any matter or antimatter state can transmit sound waves because they are the basic vibrational energy in the cosmos that has no empty space.